# UPI (Unified payment interface) impact on android app size

Tags: android

I'm investigating integrating UPI SDK. What I've learned is that it's only opened to bank as PSPs and people need to reach out to those banks to ask for the SDK.

Before reaching out to the banks, one really quick question is that after integrating the UPI SDK, how much it will increase the my app size.

Comment: 10kb for jar and 280 kb for .aar file provided by npci + 200-300kb bank's .aar file. so total about 500-600 kb size will be increased.